# Why else/others (null) appear in my query

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to run below script and was expected to get only records that having "!,@ and #). However, why do null records appear?

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN NAME LIKE ('%!%') THEN '!'
        WHEN NAME LIKE ('%@%') THEN '@'
        WHEN NAME LIKE ('%#%') THEN '#'
    END AS SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, COUNT (1) AS TOTAL
FROM 
    PERSONAL_DETAILS
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN NAME LIKE ('%!%') THEN '!'
        WHEN NAME LIKE ('%@%') THEN '@'
        WHEN NAME LIKE ('%#%') THEN '#'
    END
```

Special characters

```
(null)  227783
!       8
@       13
#       9
```

Comment: Because you don't have an else for your case and you are not filtering it in your where.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CASE` has no `ELSE`, so non-matches are assigned `NULL`.

If you do not want them, use a filter in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%!%' THEN '!'
             WHEN NAME LIKE '%@%' THEN '@'
             WHEN NAME LIKE '%#%' THEN '#'
        END) AS SPECIAL_CHARACTERS,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM PERSONAL_DETAILS
WHERE NAME LIKE '%!%' OR NAME LIKE '%@%' OR NAME LIKE '%#%'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%!%' THEN '!'
               WHEN NAME LIKE '%@%' THEN '@'
               WHEN NAME LIKE '%#%' THEN '#'
          END);
```

Notes:

- This only returns the first matching character.  So if a name contains both "!" and "#", it will only count for the "!".  If you want a full count, then ask another question.
- Parentheses are not needed around the `LIKE` pattern.
- The `WHERE` condition could be replaced with `REGEXP_LIKE(NAME< '[!@#]')`.